# Html Placeholder Attribute Issue

Tags: html, css

I'm trying using html `placeholder` attribute with the following style where an unordered list, order list, paragraph, bold text will appear:

```
Please provide social Combo offer details
For social combo lease enable or add your social media button on site
1. tweets / retweet url : website url where tweet button is enabled or twitter tweet 
   url
2. fb share : website url
3. google plus : website url
```

Is there any way to show this style on html a `placeholder` attribute?

Comment: The `placeholder` attribute is intended for form elements, to help users fill in a form. What are you really trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to style the placeholder attribute you need to use following CSS

```
:-moz-placeholder {
    font-weight: bold;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-weight: bold;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
    font-weight: bold;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Well, Mr. Alien, Is it possible to use paragraph, Order list ?

Comment: @AlexMojum Sorry am not getting you, what has paragraph and unordered list have to do with placeholder attribute?

Comment: I answer my questions that it's not possible to use markup in html placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

The `placeholder` attribute, like any HTML attribute, takes plain text as its value; no markup will be recognized there. So you cannot put e.g. an HTML list there.

And it’s meant to be used as a short placeholder text, not an explanation. You should put the filling instructions in the normal content of the page, preferably before the form or before the relevant fields.